# How do I send data from a phone to a server?

Tags: java, android, server

I am trying to send data from my phone (client) to the server using sockets.
My code is running in emulator but it is not working in my phone. In the emulator, it can send data to the server created in NetBeans.
I have tried connecting my phone and laptop to the same hotspot but still, it's not working.
My Android code is:

```
package dead.server;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText editText;
    Button button;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText=findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button=findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(this);

        Thread mythread=new Thread(new ThreadServer());
        mythread.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String message=editText.getText().toString();
        new Backgound().execute(message);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    //Sending Data to server

    class Backgound extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{

        Socket s;
        PrintWriter printWriter;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                s=new Socket("192.168.43.166",5000);
                Log.d("Server","Sent");
                printWriter=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
                printWriter.write(strings[0]);
                printWriter.flush();
                printWriter.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;

        }
    }

  //  Reciving Data from Server
    class ThreadServer implements Runnable{

        Socket s;
        ServerSocket ss;
        BufferedReader bf;
        String message;
        Handler handler=new Handler();

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                ss = new ServerSocket(5000);

                while (true){
                    s=ss.accept();
                    bf=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                    message=bf.readLine();
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                        }
                    });

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }
}
```

NetBeans IDE code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author hp
 */
public class MyServerFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
        static Socket s;
        static ServerSocket ss;
        static BufferedReader bf;
        static String message;
    /**
     * Creates new form MyServerFrame
     */
    public MyServerFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(64, 64, 64)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 249, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(87, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(79, 79, 79)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 120, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(101, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyServerFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyServerFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyServerFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MyServerFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MyServerFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        try {
                ss = new ServerSocket(5000);

                while (true){
                    s=ss.accept();
                    bf=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                    message=bf.readLine();
                    System.out.println(message);
                    jTextArea1.setText(message);


                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private static javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio (or the NetBeans) tag just because you use it: the various IDE tags should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags), and [the tagging guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Define "not working". Are you able to send data from phone to server, or vice versa? Also, it appears your phone is both a client _and_ server, not only a client.

Comment: In emulator I am able to send data to server but in my phone I am unable to send data to server.